# How to stop App Transport Security error in rspec/capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, webkit

I am using `rails 4.2.5.1` with rspec and capybara.  One of my tests gives the following message

```
2016-01-28 08:56:07.805 webkit_server[31376:18902667] App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.
```

I have isolated the cause to the following lines of code in my view

```
<audio id="bellAudio">
    <source src="/assets/ion-sounds/bell_ring.mp3" type="audio/mp3" autobuffer="autobuffer" />
    <source src="/assets/ion-sounds/bell_ring.ogg" type="audio/ogg" autobuffer="autobuffer"/>
</audio>
```

which are activated by the following coffee script:

```
play_bell = ->
    $("#bellAudio")[0].load();
    $("#bellAudio")[0].play();
```

It seems very strange to get this message for what appears to be access to a local server.  How do I prevent this message? If the answer is to use add something to an Info.plist, where do  I put that file?

Comment: I want to know too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I swapped out the mp3 for one I generated and still got the deprecation message, so it is not a real security issue with the mp3.

I changed out the `webkit driver` for `poltergeist` and the test works and I do not get the warning message any more. So I think it is just a problem with `webkit`. [This post](https://medium.com/@jaflebol/capybara-taming-the-hydrochoerus-8fcd28d70787#.8ajsxnlwy) makes strong arguments to move to poltergeist.
So that is the way I solved it, i.e. I am now using poltergeist as my web driver for Capybara.